# Send traffic over a specific port through a specific interface, using Shorewall

Tags: linux, iptables, shorewall

I have an application that does not support binding to a different interface. It currently sends outgoing connections over eth0, but I would like to send it over eth0:1 which is a virtual interface.

All the traffic is sent over a specific port range.

Is there any way I can use Shorewall to route that traffic to the appropriate interface? I would rather not use iptables, but if that's the only way then I'm willing to do so as well.